# 3.2.1 Version of Font-Awesome, icons not working

Tags: font-awesome

So i had to switch from an older version of Font Awesome to the newest version because the custom icons weren't showing up on my android phone. I heard that the 3.2.1 version fixed this issue, so i started using that. For example, previously whenever i wanted to attach an icon to a button, it would be like this:

```
<a href="account.php" data-role="button" data-icon="user">Button Name</a>
```

However after the update, when i use **data-icon="user"**, it just replaces the icon with a plus.

I've surfed through the font awesome github to see if anything on there would help. So now i'm here, still wondering what is different with the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="account.php" data-role="button" ><i class="icon-whatevericonyouwant></i>Button Name</a>
```